# Twilio - Pass custom parameters to JS client, so my client knows who's calling

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a web app that accepts incoming phone calls at a twilio number. The calls are routed through the webserver, where details on the incoming caller can be retrieved. I'm trying to pass the caller name and additional details to the agent client in javascript, BEFORE the incoming call is accepted.

After 2 days of trying, I haven't found any way to do this. I know I can pass the info back to the client through a websocket in the same server method that creates the TWiML, but that seems like a poor implementation.

Can I simply add custom parameters to the `connection` object the client sees.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but did you by any chance succeed?

Comment: @SagiRika even I'm trying for that, [this twilio article](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-Custom-Information-via-Requests-to-Twilio) didn't work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Just use it in your javascript file and you will get the custom parameter that you sent from the backend during calls. If there are some conflicts with the Twilio library when you check the parameter then it will not go to inside. I had the same problem and my problem is solved.

```
connection.customParameters.get("parameter_name")
```